# Android Beacons not found: Google Beacon Dashboard

Tags: estimote, google-beacon-platform

In my android manifest, I have put like this.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.nearby.messages.API_KEY"
android:value="somethingnsomethingsomething" />

<!-- Required for Nearby Connections -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

In my MainActivity, I wrote like this.

```
private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        return;
    }
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();
}


@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onConnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mMessageListener = new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFound(Message message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found message: " + new String(message.getContent()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLost(Message message) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found message: " + new String(message.getContent()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    SubscribeOptions options = new SubscribeOptions.Builder()
            .setStrategy(Strategy.BLE_ONLY)
            .build();
    Nearby.getMessagesClient(this).subscribe(mMessageListener, options);
}
```

[image]

[image]

I am using estimote beacon and I think I successfully added in Google Beacon Dashboard. But I cannot discover my beacon. Is there something wrong?

Comment: You also need INTERNET permission to connect go Google servers. and to set up your account credentials to use the Nearby API.

Comment: I see "failed to connect" in the the Provisioning section, did you manage to provision the beacon? As in, set/enable the Eddystone-URL/Eddystone-UID to broadcast?

Comment: @heypiotr I cannot manage to provision. Last time, I have to manually register my beacon using API. How shall I d?

Comment: @davidgyoung yes. I gave internet permission also.

Comment: @KhantThuLinn so if I understand correctly, you used Estimote's tools to enable Eddystone UID or URL on the beacon, and then registered it manually in Google Cloud via an API? That should work. I can see your dashboard says "this beacon is active", which I believe means something is actually detecting it. Otherwise, IIRC, it'd be saying smth like "low activity". Are you sure about the `buildGoogleApiClient` and `onConnected` part in your code? I see the Nearby Messages example doesn't do this and uses `onCreate`/`onStart` lifecycle methods instead.

Comment: @heypiotr ah yes. I have tried with onCreate/onStart as well but it cannot detect also. When I use beacon tool app, it cannot provision my bluetooth. Can it be issue also?

Comment: Provisioning is only if you want to configure the beacon broadcasting via the Beacon Tools app. But if you've already configured the beacon via manufacturer-specific tools (here, the Estimote app I guess), you should be good.